# How to extend control templates (for example with a third color)

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I do have a control template for WPF button. Within the template I can use the Fillcolor and Backcolor of the button. But is it possible to define a third color that can be used in the template and later on in a real button?

Here an example of a circular button. I would like to add a color for the ToggleButton.IsChecked state.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="White" Stroke="Gray"/>
        <Label x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="content" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure wether or not you want to bind this to a property or just use a brush resource, Here is an example using a Resource:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</SolidColorBrush >
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="White" Stroke="Gray"/>
                <Label x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="content" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}"  Height="50" Width="50"></ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Base on the clarification that you wanted to be able to set the property on the ToggleButton you will need to use a [Dependecy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) here is a quick example:

**Custom Control**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public class CustomControl2 : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton 
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty myFillColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("myFillColor",typeof(SolidColorBrush),typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton));    
        static CustomControl2()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl2)));
        }

        public SolidColorBrush myFillColor
        {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(myFillColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(myFillColorProperty, value); }

        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="White" Stroke="Gray"/>
                <Label x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=myFillColor, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="content" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <my:CustomControl2 myFillColor="Red" Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}"  Height="50" Width="50"></my:CustomControl2>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: In your example you can not access or change the color/brush in the ToggleButton instance itself. So your ControlPressedColor in the control template is quite static. My question was if I can define something like <ToggleButton MyColor="Red" /> whereas MyColor is used in the template.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I thought it's possible without implementing a derived button class. But this will work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your ColorBrush to a ResourceDictionary, give it a key via the x:Key property and reference that resource via the StaticResource or DynamicResource markup extension from both the template and the "real" button (by which I assume you mean an instance of Button, probably defined in xaml). This requires that you merge in the dictionary that contains that key via the ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries property.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySharedColor"  Color="Red"/>       
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border Background="{StaticResource MySharedColor}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>        
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>       
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MySharedColor}"/>    
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't understand the part with the brush. Can your give me a sample in XAML about that? I edited my question above and added a ToggleButton template for which I would like to have a third color for the IsChecked state.

Comment: also Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource='{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}'}" is the same as saying {TemplateBinding Foreground}

Comment: But BorderBrush is not a new property of a button. My question is if I can add new properties like ToggleButton.MyOwnColor and use that in the control template for drawing.

Comment: yes, but why would you want to. If you're hell bent on doing it that way you could look into attached properties. Dr wpf has some good snippets to generate the boiler plate code. To me this would be mixing concerns.